# Modifying array type if necessary inside a checking function

Tags: python, numpy, reference

I have a function that modifies an input array dtype if necessary:

```
def f(ar,dtype):
    if ar.dtype!=dtype:
         ar = ar.astype(dtype)
```

This, however, does not work because I change the reference inside the function and the outer scope is unaware of it (as far as I understood).

Will this be the most efficient version:

```
def f(ar,dtype):
    if ar.dtype!=dtype:
         ar = ar.astype(dtype)
    return ar
```

And I would call it as `ar=f(ar,np.float32)`. The thing that I am not sure about is if there are unnecessary memory transfers? Does this function return a reference, or does it copy a newly created array into the module scope?

Comment: You made a new array in the function.  You did not modify the original.

Comment: @hpaulj I am aware of that. My question is whether this way of enforcing datatype with an auxiliary function is optimal. Specifically, when I call `ar=f(ar,np.float32)` is the array created inside my function is copied into `ar`, or is it just created inside of the function and a reference is passed by the return statement?

Comment: `ar=f(...)` assigns the new object (doesn't have to be an array) to the variable `ar`.  Only `ar[:] =...` copies values into an existing array object.  As a general rule, in Python assignment and passing variables in and out of functions is by reference.  The main new thing with `numpy` is the concept of a `view`.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the docs for `astype`, and `np.array`.  `ar = ar.astype(dtype, copy=False)` or `np.array(ar, dtype=dtype, copy=False)` would let you skip the `dtype` test.  If so, you might even need to use an extra utility function like this.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer

Comment: Just to mention, one more quite ugly, but sometimes convenient way to do it is to use `global` keyword. Thus the array is not passed to the function, but exists in the outer scope. Function does `global arr` inside. In this case you have the functionality of replacing the variable.

Comment: @Slowpoke I prefer not to mess up with globals unless absolutely necessary. But thanks